# Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS black screen after grub

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, raid

Motherboard: Asus H170-PRO

CPU: Intel Core i5-6500

HDD: 1TB x2

From the BIOS I made the following changes:
AdvancedMode -> Boot -> Secure Boot -> Os Type = Other OS (instead of Windows)

Ez Tuning Wizard -> Created "Super speed raid" with the 2 identical harddisks.

Intel Rapid Storage is ON.

Saved and restarted.

Installed Ubuntu (without errors). I'm using a cd-rom, not a USB key.

Now after grub i get a black screen with white text lines going..
after 2-3 seconds the whole screen is black and stuck here.

EDIT:
tried without raid.. same problem :(

EDIT:
Tried enabling Legacy BIOS mode and re-installing ubuntu. Now the computer freezes at grub menu.

Ubuntu server 15.10 worked fine. No problems. The only problem is that it's not a LTS version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem(I also use Asus H170-PRO and 14.04.3 LTS) and solved it by adding `nomodeset` to the boot parameter. The following post helped me.

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: what a pity :( by the time you answered my question i have already setup Ubuntu 15.10 which just worked (but it's not LTS)